# Weak Convergence If and Only If (Pointwise) Convergence of Characteristic Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

[image: Theorem 4.15]

This is actually a theorem from lecture notes, with the corresponding proof. Unfortunately, it doesn't prove the last bit, or mention it at all (!), and I have a question about the penultimate bit. This is the definition of weak convergence being used:

> Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\Bbb R^d$ and let $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of Borel probability measures on $\Bbb R^d$.
>
> We say that $(\mu_n)$ *converges weakly* to $\mu$, written $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$, if $\mu_n(f) \rightarrow \mu(f)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all bounded, continuous functions $f:\Bbb R^d \rightarrow \Bbb R$.
>
> We say that the sequence $(X_n)$ of random variables on $\Bbb R^d$ *converges weakly* to $X$ if $\mu_{X_n} \Rightarrow \mu_X$.

Firstly, consider the penultimate claim (*If a sequence...*). What I don't understand is why [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379239/characteristic-function-converges-pointwise) is not a counter-example to the claim. ($\phi$ is the characteristic function.)

Secondly, consider the final claim (*Conversely, if...*). No proof was given in the lecture notes. I think I have a solution, but I'm not sure; if someone could look over my answer (given as an answer below), then I'd be most appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the first,  $\phi_{X_n}(t) \to \phi_X(t)$ says, not merely that CFs converges pointwise to some function, but that it convergest to the CF of the random variable $X$, hence $\phi_X(t)$ is continuous at $t=0$. This is not true in the counterexample.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I did notice that the limit function in the other answer wasn't continuous, but forgetting that the characteristic function needs to be continuous (not so for the density function (pdf) yes?).

Comment: @SamOT do you mind sharing the references of the book where you saw this theorem?

Comment: @Anyway142 They were lecture notes for the Cambridge undergraduate course *Probability and Measure*. The lecture notes were written by Alan Sola, I believe. They don't seem to still be available—I remember a friend sent them to me from the year before. James Norris has lecture notes for the same course: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pm.pdf. His numbering is a bit different; it's Theorem 7.7.1 there. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X_n \Rightarrow X$, ie $\mu_{X_n} \Rightarrow \mu_X$. We desire to show that
$\phi_{X_n}(\xi) \rightarrow \phi_{X_n}$ as $n \to \infty$ $\forall \xi \in \Bbb R^d.$ Write $\mu_n = \mu_{X_n}$ and $\mu = \mu_X$.

Since, by definition, $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$, in particular we have that, for each (fixed) $\xi \in \Bbb R^d$, $\mu_n(e^{i x \cdot \xi}) \rightarrow \mu(e^{i x \cdot \xi})$. Thus,
$$ \begin{align} |\phi_{X_n} - \phi_X| & = |\hat \mu_{X_n}(\xi) - \hat \mu_X(\xi) | \\
& = | \int_{\Bbb R^d} e^{i x \cdot \xi} \, d\mu_{X_n}(x) - \int_{\Bbb R^d} e^{i x \cdot \xi} \, d\mu_{X_n}(x) | \\
& = | \mu_n(e^{i x \cdot \xi}) - \mu(e^{i x \cdot \xi}) | \\
& \rightarrow 0.
\end{align}$$
as $n \to \infty$. (No need for the dominated convergence theorem.)

Also, this is for *fixed* $\xi$, so I have shown *pointwise*, not *uniform* convergence.

Comment: No, your proof is *not* valid. In general, we cannot expect uniform convergence. First of all: $$\hat{\mu}_{X_n}(\xi) \neq \int \mu_{X_n}(x) e^{\imath \, x \xi} \, dx.$$ The expression $\mu_{X_n}(x)$ doesn't even make sense. Instead it should read $$\hat{\mu}_{X_n}(\xi) = \int e^{\imath \, x \xi} \, d\mu_{X_n}(x).$$ (Note that this is an integral with respect to the *distribution* $\mu_{X_n}$ of the random variable $X_n$.)

Comment: Yes I see. This is exactly what I thought the issue would be. What do I then do with $|\hat\mu_{X_n}(\xi)-\hat\mu_X(\xi)|$? I realise that we won't necessarily get *uniform* convergence, but we should get pointwise. How would I rectify my error?

Comment: What's your definiton of weak convergence? (There are several ones; that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: Good point - I have added it into the question.

Comment: I see. Then the hint goes like that: Note that for each fixed $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the function $f(x) := e^{\imath \, x \cdot \xi}$ is bounded and continuous.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. My issue was that I was thinking about "$\mu(x)$", which I couldn't determine a meaning for - since it is meaningless. I've now updated my answer.

Comment: The lecture notes actually define the characteristic function as
$$ \phi_X(\xi) = \hat \mu_X (\xi) = \Bbb E[e^{i X \cdot \xi}]. $$
This should have given me the required hint to do it as you said, but I didn't think about it because it has an $\Bbb E,$ not a $\mu$ - amateur hour! Won't do that again (hopefully!)!

Comment: You are welcome. (And no, we don't need the dominated convergence theorem.)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note the definition of the characteristic function:
$$\varphi_X(x) = \mathbb{E}(e^{i\langle x, X \rangle}).$$
The weak convergence of $(X_n)$ towards X means that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) = \mathbb{E}(f(X)) $$
for all continuous and bounded functions $\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$. since $y \mapsto e^{i\langle x, y \rangle} $ is continuous and bounded for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, we obtain pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions.